# Android:Parse custom forum Tags

Tags: java, android, html, json, parsing

I want to parse some strings which contains custom forum tags in them,like:

```
[url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xxx]----sent from my Sony Ericsson LT28h,Android 4.2.1[/url]
```

and show this tag string in a textview to be a clickable link [----sent from my Sony Ericsson LT28h,Android 4.2.1](http://www.google.com)

I tried the Html.fromhtml and use a custom taghandler, but it seems only support custom tags starts with "<" and ends ">"
Any suggestions?

Comment: Parse json, format your link as html and than do Html.fromHtml("yourhtmlstring") ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way is to write a custom handler for these, check for a sample code below, it may give you a hint (note this code will return you inner value of [url]...[/url] tags you need to create one more iteration for [url=....] tag using same logic to get url's value):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MyHandler {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
                "\[url.*\](.*)\[/url\]",
                Pattern.DOTALL
            );

        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(
                "[url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xxx]----sent from my Sony Ericsson LT28h,Android 4.2.1[/url]"
            );

        if(matcher.matches()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't expect a general method to know all possible custom tags which forums come up with of course. 
So you'll need to do it manually.

I guess your best bet is to set up a method where you replace the custom tags with their 'official' HTML tag, if they have one. 
You can just use String.replace() for this.